# How to create image from numpy float32 array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a `numpy.ndarray` array which contains values of `float32`. The images should be dimensions 226×226. I tried to use `PIL.Image` to create the image but I got an error. I read that `PIL.Image.fromarray` require an object and mode, and for float I need to call `fromarray` with `'F'` as I tried.

This is what I tried to do:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(slice56, mode='F')
#type(slice56) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
#slice56 = array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1860, in fromarray
    return frombuffer(mode, size, obj, "raw", mode, 0, 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1805, in frombuffer
    return apply(fromstring, (mode, size, data, decoder_name, args))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1743, in fromstring
    im = new(mode, size)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1710, in new
    return Image()._new(core.fill(mode, size, color))
TypeError: argument 2 must be sequence of length 2, not 1
```

Can anyone suggest an idea how to do it? Or how to solve this error?

Comment: What is the shape of your array? It seems like you have a 1D array. You can reshape it to make it a 2D array.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would agree with DavidG's answer being a quick solution to plot an image from a numpy array. However, if you have a very good reason for sticking with `PIL.Image`, the closest approach to what you've already done would be something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

slice56 = np.random.random((226, 226))

# convert values to 0 - 255 int8 format
formatted = (slice56 * 255 / np.max(slice56)).astype('uint8')
img = Image.fromarray(formatted)
img.show()
```

It will then produce something like below given random numbers:

[image: PIL Image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't need specific `PIL.Image`. I need to create an image from the array and I found this. If you have a better solution I would be glad to try it. For your answer, I tried it and got `TypeError: Do not understand data.` Do you have any idea why did this happen?

Comment: is your data 1D numpy array? if yes, do this for `slice56`: `slice56 = slice56.reshape((226,226))`. Give me an update if that doesn't work.

Comment: @jtitusj note that division by max value of the data changes the range of the data, which may not be what is desired.

Comment: @AlexKreimer I totally agree that it will change the range of the data. However, the original intention was just to make an image out of the array so I believe that this solution is actually valid. The problem was already considered solved so I believe it satisfied what the user wanted. Of course there are things that we can also put into consideration like does the range matter , does presence of negative values matter, etc but that's going beyond what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.misc` is my favorite way of doing it. It's cleaner and it is done in just one line.
Look how nice it is:

```
import scipy.misc
img = scipy.misc.toimage(slice56, mode='L')
```

Please check [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.toimage.html) for the official docs.

Comment: `scipy.misc.toimage()` was deprecated in Scipy 1.0.0 and completely removed in version 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `John Titus Jungao` the problem solved. The array was 1D so I did the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

slice56 = slice56.reshape((226,226))
formatted = (slice56 * 255 / np.max(slice56)).astype('uint8')
img = Image.fromarray(formatted)
img.save('slice56.png')
```

and that's it.